# How to update getServicelocator to zend 3

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I'm new to zend3, and I came across a problem, getservicelocator no longer exists in version 3, I'm working with a controller, I wanted to know how to implement this migration,  Anyone know how to make this change

```
namespace Base\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\ArrayAdapter;

abstract class AbstractController extends AbstractActionController
{

    /**
     *  Entity manager
     * @var
     */
    protected $em;
    /** Entity
     * @var
     */
    protected $entity;
    /**
     * Controller
     * @var
     */
    protected $controller;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $route;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $service;
    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $form;

    private $configTable;
    /**
     * AbstractController constructor.
     */
    abstract function __construct();
...
/**
     * 
     * @return \Zend\Http\Response
     */
    public function excluirAction()
    {
        $service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get($this->service);
        $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id',0);
        // Abstract service
        if ($service->remove(array('id' => $id))) {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Success');
        } else {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Error');
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($this->route, array('controller' => $this->controller));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture is not really good in your case, why would you have an action in an abstract controller...

The right way would be for the controller not to be abstract and pass the service through the constructor.

The wrong way would be to inject the service locator using [a delegator](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-servicemanager/delegators/).

The idea of removing the service locator is to be clearer on the dependencies of the class, so the code is way more readable (like "oh, I see this class needs ... and ... to do **NAME_OF_THE_ACTION**").
Also, it highly improve the code testability (you know what dependencies to mock/fake).